# Mail app supporting O365 Categories

Tags: pantheon-mail

The only thing stopping me from switching to eOS/Linux (from macOS) is **Outlook Categories** (I use O365 Exchange). Yeah, I know it sounds dumb, but it's a big deal to me because I have hundreds of email messages tagged with one or multiple custom categories so I can quickly filter out what I'm looking for.

I have been unable to find an email client that supports Outlook Categories. Does one exist?

Comment: Have you looked at Hiri email.

Comment: @JeffWilson yeah #hiri was the first app I tried. It doesn’t support O365 categories. Furthermore, contacting them for support is impossible so I have no interest in giving them my business.